# setting session variable for paramiko session

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, paramiko

Does anyone know how to make environment variables registered for 
exec_command calls when using SSHClient?

I'm using a basic script that instantiates the SSHClient class, connects to another computer using the connect method, then sends out commands using the exec_command method. However, none of the environment variables seem to be registered when I try to issue commands. I can do basic things like 'ls' and see the stdout, but when trying to run installed programs, the fact that the environment variables are missing makes it impossible to run them. Using ssh in the command line to do the same thing works, as the environment variables for the user are set.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko

ssh.connect('mymachine',username='myname',password='pass')    
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('cd /myfolder/path')
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('ls')

....

....

ssh.close()
```

Note: I can't change my directory in paramiko. I appended the `cd` command in the followup command in a single `ssh.exec_command('cd /dddd/ddd;ls')`. I have given `ls` as an example but my actual followup command is different.

Comment: Have you tried adding them via [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ)?

Comment: I am looking to set the 'TZ' env variable as well :| How do we go about setting the 'TZ' env variable using `os.environ`, if it's not supported in `paramiko`?? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Since release 2.1.0 2016-12-09 , you can add an environment variable dictionary to the **exec_command**:

```
import paramiko
paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
k =   paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("<private_key_file>")
ssh.connect(<hostname>,username=<username>,pkey=k)
env_dict={"LC_TELEPHONE":"ET_HOME","LC_MEASUREMENT":"MILES_APART"}
stdin , stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo $LC_TELEPHONE; echo "..."; echo $LC_MEASUREMENT',environment=env_dict)
print stdout.read()
```

output:

```
ET_HOME
...
MILES_APART
```

But why did I choose LC_TELEPHONE and LC_MEASUREMENT? Because those are two of the few environments that the target host's ssh config allows me to set:

```
grep AcceptEnv /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

output:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
```

In other words, this doesn't work:

```
env_dict={"HELLO":"WORLD","GOODBYE":"CRUEL_WORLD"}
stdin , stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo $HELLO; echo '...'; echo $GOODBYE")
print stdout.read()
```

output:

```
...
```

As the documentation warns, the environment variables are silently rejected 
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/client.html
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.set_environment_variable

If you cannot control the target server's sshd config, putting the environment variables into a file and sourcing it works:

```
stdin , stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cat .set_env;source .set_env; echo $HELLO; echo '...'; echo $GOODBYE")
print stdout.read()
```

output:

```
# begin .set_env
HELLO="WORLD"
GOODBYE="CRUEL_WORLD"
# end .set_env
WORLD
...
CRUEL_WORLD
```

Comment: I cannot find the environment argument in exec_command, it shows in the documentation but I don't see it in the exec_command in client.py

Comment: There are two `exec_command` methods in paramiko. There is [client.exec_command](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) and then there is [channel.exec_command](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.exec_command). The first one, `client.exec_command`, has the argument. The second one does not.

Comment: Anyways, since sshd in default configuration rejects most env variables, `exec_command(environment=)` is not the way to go, unless the envs you need to set are locale-related (these tend to be accepted).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
client.connect(myhostname, theport, myuser, thepass)
stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('cd /tmp;pwd;ls -al')
#returns your output
print stdout.read()
```

which all works fine for me. If you have special environment Variables you might
have to set them on the remote command prompt. Maybe it helps if you write the
variables into a myENV file and then call

`stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('source ./myEnv')`

Did you tried something like that?

Comment: does not work for me. As can be seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938993/python-using-env-variables-of-remote-host-with-ssh the trick is to write it in one client.exec_command('source $PROFILE; CommandToExcecute')

Answer (score 1):

You can do: `client.exec_command(..., get_pty=True)`.

This will make paramiko allocate a pseudo terminal, similar to `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem too. And besides the above approaches, I also fixed the problem by using the following approach:
e.g.,

```py
...
                bin_paths = '/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin'
                path_prefix = 'PATH=$PATH:%s && ' % bin_paths
                command = path_prefix + command
                ssh.exec_command(command=command)
```