# Python - using env variables of remote host with / SSH

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Basically I'm writing a python script that will ssh onto various servers and to execute scripts.  The problem is that these scripts use an env variable to start.  Ie the script is test.sh but we use an env variable to launch it, run test.sh.

So far the routes I have taken, such as Paramiko module execute commands but do not actually take on the env variables.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('testserver' )

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cd /home/test/;$run ./test.sh')
print stdout.readlines()
print stderr.readlines()
ssh.close()
```

Is there a way to use paramiko? Or another way I should take?

Thanks

@ Rob

I edited the script to test. The $run variable is coming back blank.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('whoami;echo hello; echo $run ; echo goodbye')

['testuser\n', 'hello\n', '\n', 'goodbye\n']
[]
```

@ Rob part 2

Logging onto the server, I am able to echo $run and it returns the correct path/script
I also checked and this is an env variable that is set in the .profile.  I feel like python is not invoking the .profile .

Comment: Assuming you fix the syntax errors, what happens when you run the above program?

Comment: _"the script is test.sh but we use an env variable to launch it, run test.sh"_  I can't figure out what this means.  How do you use an env variable to launch a script?

Comment: That should work perfectly, assuming that the remote shell's `.profile` or similar start-up sets the `$run` environment variable. You can test this by `ssh.exec_command('echo hello ; echo $run ; echo goodbye')`.

Comment: @JimGarrison - the clue is in the code. He meant `$run test.sh`.

Comment: Then you haven't set the `run` environment variable on the remote machine. How are you trying to set `run`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ssh.exec_command` doesn't interpret the remote `.profile`. Try this:

```
ssh.exec_command('. .profile ; cd /home/test/;$run ./test.sh')
```

Comment: hmm is that a ./.profile?  It still is returning blank for $run.  It does not throw any errors though.

Comment: The first command is either `. .profile` or `. ./.profile`. It is not `./.profile`.

Comment: Awesome, it worked with **. ./.profile** Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[*Plumbum*](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to the rescue.

Among other things, it provides a nifty interface, leveraging paramiko (see [ParamikoMachine](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote.html#guide-paramiko-machine)), and also lets you manipulate the [remote environment](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote.html#working-directory-and-environment).